# Comparing objects in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to compare one object to each object in table correctly? Can i do something like `if(object == $.each(table)){ do something }`

what is the easiest way to compare objects with table of objects?

Comment: What is `object`?  What is `table`?  What defines equality?  You certainly can't compare with a call to `$.each()`, that wouldn't produce anything meaningful.

Comment: I need to get random card, next check is there that card in my hand already. If yes , draw next card until get new. Is there a way to do this in do-while condition?

Comment: Well, you can loop over the known cards and compare the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if a given value exists in a list of values, you can loop over that list:

```
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    if (object == table[i]) {
        found = true;
        break; // no need to keep looping
    }
}
if (found === true) {
    // the value was found in the collection
}
```

Depending on what `object` and `table` are, you may need to compare specific properties and not the entire objects.  For example:

```
if (object.someKeyValue === table[i].someKeyValue)
```

The definition of "equality" isn't always a straightforward thing, and outside the scope of simple scalar values you're pretty much responsible for defining what makes any two objects "equal".  If you have to compare multiple fields, you may abstract it into a function which internally compares them:

```
if (areEqual(object, table[i]))
```

(You might give things more meaningful names of course, this is just in keeping with the contrived example in the question.)

Ultimately, the overall structure is really going to be the same.  Given a value and a collection of values, you would examine what's in the collection and compare its contents with the value to find (or not find) a match.